# Angular/Karma: Mock Data Undefined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I'm trying to create a unit test that checks if a GET request returns the correct amount of items, but I'm using mock data to do this.

My test looks like this:

**test.js**

```
describe('Customer Controller', function () {
    var controller;
    var customers = mockData.getMockCustomers(); // fake customers (5 customers)

    beforeEach(function() {
      bard.appModule('app');
      bard.inject('$controller', '$q', '$rootScope');

      var cs = {
        getCustomers: function() {
          return $q.when(customers);
        }
      };

      controller = $controller('customersCtrl', {
        CustomerService: cs
      });
    });

    it('should return 5 customers', function() {
      $rootScope.$apply();
      expect(controller.customers).to.have.length(5);
    });
});
```

I keep getting this error when I run the test:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

It looks like `controller.customers` is coming back as `undefined` for some reason. Am I mocking the data correctly?

I'm very new to this and can't work out what I'm doing wrong. I don't even know how to debug such an issue.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

My controller looks like this:

```
function customersCtrl(dataservice) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.customers = [];

  fetchCustomers();

  function fetchCustomers() {
    return dataservice.getCustomers()
    .then(function(data) {
      vm.customers = data.data;
      return vm.customers ;
    });
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've put a console.log in the test, and my customers variable is returning 5 objects which appear to be empty. Perhaps this is the issue?

[image]

Comment: just out of interest have you changed names of your controllers, or perhaps you have a copy and paste mistake, your initialising 'scoreListCtrl' rather than 'customersCtrl'

Comment: Yeah, I've changed the names to post this example.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into $httpBackend? unit tests don't actually hit your database if thats what you're expecting. you have to mockup your own response.

ie:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/MyEndPoint).respond([{}, {}, {}]);
```

then you can test for length of 3 or whatever you want

Comment: I would recommend this approach as well, not only will you find it easier to work with, but as its a more standard approach you'll find lots of documentation on how to do it.

Comment: That's what I was expecting my `cs` to do. Mock the data coming back. How would I refactor my code to use that `$httpBackend` method above?

Comment: actually since looking into your example it would be better to keep mocking CS, thats your dependency mock that. CS should be tested with $httpBackend

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

**New answer, recommends using sinon spys**

I use mocha for some node tests, using chai & sinon - here is an example using a sinon stub.

```
var sinon = require('sinon');

describe('Customer Controller', function () {
        var controller;
        var customers = mockData.getMockCustomers(); // fake customers (5 customers)

    beforeEach(function() {
      bard.appModule('app');
      bard.inject('$controller', '$q', '$rootScope');

      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve(customers);
      var cs = {
         fetchCustomers: sinon.stub().returns(deferred.promise)
      };

      controller = $controller('scoreListCtrl', {
        CustomerService: cs
      });
    });

    it('should return 5 customers', function() {
      $rootScope.$apply();
      expect(controller.customers).to.have.length(5);
    });
});
```

**Original Answer below, recommends using jasmine spys**

Have you used jasmine spy's before? I'd use them, this probably wont be a copy and paste answer for you but should give you the general direction to go in.

```
describe('Customer Controller', function () {
    var controller;
    var customers = mockData.getMockCustomers(); // fake customers (5 customers)

    beforeEach(function() {
      bard.appModule('app');
      bard.inject('$controller', '$q', '$rootScope');

      var cs = {};
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve(customers);
      spyOn(cs, 'fetchCustomers').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

      controller = $controller('scoreListCtrl', {
        CustomerService: cs
      });
    });

    it('should return 5 customers', function() {
      $rootScope.$apply();
      expect(controller.customers).to.have.length(5);
    });
});
```

You can checkout more about jasmine spys here: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Comment: I'm using Mocha instead of Jasmine.

Comment: updated the answer to talk about sinon spies as well, gave code example